# WearOS PeriodicWork with Internet Connection

Tags: android, networking, wear-os

now i am programming a WearOS Watch.
And i have following quesiton.

I have a periodic work:

```
    private val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED) // Require network connectivity
        .build()
```

Since now i am not sure, if it only works via Wifi or Bluetooth as well, when iit is conntected to a Phone.

Can somebody help me here out?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says:

> Any working network connection is required for this work.

I presume it will work with wifi and/or bluetooth.